# I want all projects in one build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, artifacts, azure-artifacts

I will explain my scenario. I want one build which contain all the artifacts of three projects.
1.project1 with artifact
2.project2 with artifact
3.project3 will have 3 artifacts.
New to CICD. Please help me

Comment: what type of project you are working with? dotnet , java or what ?

Comment: We are using dotnet core

Comment: So basically you are a single solution (.sln) having 3 different projects (.csproj) and you want to get the artifact of all 3 different projects in a single artifact?

Comment: No jayendran. I'm having 3 solution solution1,solution2,solution3 and in solution 3 we have 3 projects so what I want is artifact for solution1& solution2& for 3 artifacts for 3 projects in solution3.so finally I I it will be 5 artifacts for the build

Comment: you can dotnet build task for each `projects` and finally publish all the artifacts into `artifactstagingdirectory`